# Regex replacement in java

Tags: java, regex

I'm attempting to make the following replacement in java

```
@Test
public void testReplace(){
    String str = "1JU3C_2.27.CBT";
    String find = "(\\d*)\\.(\\d*)";
    String replace = "$1,$2";
    String modified = str.replaceAll(find, replace);
    System.out.println(modified);
    assertEquals("1JU3C_2,27.CBT", modified); //fails
}
```

However both full stops seem to be getting replaced. I'm looking at replacing only the numeric decimal. (i.e expecting output 1JU3C_2,27.CBT)

Comment: What is the actual output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)` instead of `(\\d*)\\.(\\d*)`.

Your regex asks to replace zero or more digits followed by a dot, followed by zero or more digits. So **.** in **.CBT** is matched as it has a dot with zero digits on both sides.

1JU3C_2.27.CBT has two dots with zero or more digits on both sides.

If you want to convert string like **5.67.8** to **5,67,8** use lazy matching as `(\\d+?)\\.(\\d+?)`.

Answer (score 1):

> *

stands for zero or more times, try replacing it with

> +

Answer (score 0):

Instead do this:

```
public void testReplace()
{
   String str = "1JU3C_2.27.CBT";
   String modified = str.replaceFirst("[.]", ",");
   System.out.println(modified);
   assertEquals("1JU3C_2,27.CBT", modified); 
}
```

Comment: That passes the test, but I need to use regex so that input like 1JU3C_227.CBT is not erroneously replaced

Comment: You want to replace "." by "," only if it occured more than once...is that right??